# Airflow SQL Server connection installation

Tags: connection, airflow

I am trying to install the Airflow SQL Server connection type in Airflow hosted in Docker Service.

After installing the required python packages in the CLI, I still don't see the SQL Server connection type in the Airflow UI.

Airflow version: v2.6

Python Packages installed:

```
pip install 'apache-airflow==1.10.12' --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-1.10.12/constraints-3.7.txt" \
pip install apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql==1.0.0
pip install pymssql
```

Not sure if I need to update any other files in AirFlow? Please help.